# multiple is select tagHelper generated automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The following code causes this error(@(Model.IsMultipleChoices?"multiple":"")):

> The tag helper 'select' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area

```
 <select asp-for="@Model.FeatureValues"  @(Model.IsMultipleChoices?"multiple":"")>
<option></option>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FeatureValues)
```

what's the solution?

There is another problem! And that multiple is still generated automatically !!! Even if IsMultipleChoices f is false! !!!

Comment: Tag Helpers doesnt allow C# in element's attribute. Try this. I also added the end select tag.                                      
<select asp-for="@Model.FeatureValues"  multiple="@(Model.IsMultipleChoices)">
<option></option>
</select>

Comment: @GargiD.Chakravarty : 
There is another problem! And that multiple is still generated automatically !!!